# How can I create a sub-directory where my group has no write permissions?

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo, group

I am working in my `Tomcat` deployment directory. The files in the directory have the permission:

```
drwxrwsr-x. 10 tomcat www  4.0K Mar 15 15:14 webapps
```

A sample sub-directory within `webapps` looks like this:

```
drwxr-sr-x.  6 tomcat www 4.0K Mar 15 15:19 oldApps
```

While I am a member of group `www`, I am able to create directories in `oldApps`. This is despite the group `www` having no write permissions on `oldApps`.

I have a line in my `sudoers` file that allows `mkdir` to members of `www` group. I am not able to understand how I can write to the folder `oldApps` without any write permissions on the folder.

**Update**:
Ok, I get that I might be running the `mkdir` command as root, thus allowing me to create folders. How do I remove the line from `sudoers` and still be able to create directories?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you can create the directory is due to the fact you are using `sudo`. The actual `mkdir` command runs (most probably) as `tomcat`. Since the set-gid attribute is set the group on the new directory is still `www`

Update:

To add permissions to another user and/or group you can use extended ACLs:

```
setfacl -d -m g:www:rwx oldApps
setfacl -m g:www:rwx oldApps
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question. I realize that making changes to `sudoers` is not ideal. How do I create a directory without a line in `sudoers`?

Comment: You might use extended ACLs, see updated answer.

Comment: I tried both commands as you suggested, but the I am still unable to delete any files/folders within `oldApps`.

Comment: For existing directories you may need to set the extended ACLs recursively. See man `setfacl` and search for 'recursive'

Comment: The /etc/fstab entry does not have an acl in the options taken while mounting. Could that also be a reason why this is not mounting correctly? Do I need to remount with acl options set?

Comment: I believe acls are allowed by default and that you can explicitly allow (acl) and/or disallow (noacl) using the mount options. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists for details. What is the filesystem you are using? What is the output of the `setfacl` and `getfacl` commands?

Answer (score 0):

You actually answered your own question: The reason you can create a subdirectory where your group has no write permissions, is because you have a line in your `sudoers` file that allows `mkdir` to members of your group.

Perhaps you are confused about the purpose of the `sudoers` file and the `sudo` command: You don't need to explicitly allow every command that you intend for someone to run; in fact you *shouldn't* do this.

`sudo` is for running *privileged* commands.  You should only give someone `sudo` access for commands that you wish them to be able to run *as root*.  With full `sudo` access for any command, the user can do *anything*, regardless of the permissions settings of individual files and directories.

Comment: Agreed. I figured I was running the `mkdir` command as root. How do I get the ability to run `mkdir` on `www` if I did not have the entry in the `sudoers` file

Comment: @Sriram, `chmod g+x oldApps`, you mean?  Not sure I get the question.

Comment: I meant if I remove the entry in the sudoers file, I cannot create the directory. How do I remove the `sudoers` entry and still create the sub-directory?

Comment: @Sriram, the most straightforward way would be to give your group write permissions on that directory, unless you have some reason not to.  `chmod g+w oldApps` (my last comment had a typo, sorry.)

Comment: This did not work. I am not able to delete any sub-directory of oldApps - with sudo or without.